# Browsers load an broken version of CSS that's on the server, and not the original CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, rendering, hosting

So I am building a website and having a problem. I have only 1 HTML file, 1 CSS file, and 1 very small javascript file. The directories are all correct, and the CSS amd javascript files are correctly linked in the HTML, but here's the problem:

When I put the files on the server and opened the website from my domain (daveyloper.com), the website is all janky. The dev tools on Chrome and Firefox show that the CSS file is different than the one I see on the server. For example, the CSS file on the server has more lines than the one in dev tools. Some styles are also altered, like my `#logolink` and `#logoimg`, as well as `.project-slides p`.

Another thing I noticed is that when I upload the HTML and CSS files on the server, both with filezilla and the cpanel, the size of the file changes, becomes a little bit smaller.

Also, it seems the problem is mainly related to media queries, as most things in desktop view work fine, but in mobile view which I made using media queries everything is broken.

So here are my questions:

1. Why is the CSS file that's loaded by the browsers altered from the one that's on the server?
2. Why does the CSS file load properly from my hard drive, but does the abovementioned when loaded from the server?
3. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I am using infinityfree for hosting, and filezilla to load files on it, and VSCode as my IDE. I'm linking my current code below:
https://github.com/Lursmani/daveyloper.com

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if the code there is all jank, it's my first time building a website and I started from scratch.

Comment: Have you got a cacheing problem? Is your browser picking up an old version that is still in its cache?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Cloudflare had a cached version of the website from yesterday and the browsers were loading that instead of the live website. I cleared Cloudflare's cache and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you for your help!